# How to connect ASP.NET config to SQL Server instead of SQL Server Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, web

I configured my SQL Server database using `aspnet_regsql.exe`. Everything worked great. I then added the new connection string in my `web.config` file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <clear />
   <remove name="LocalSqlServer" />
   <add name="SQLConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Provider=ProvName;Server=Sname;Database=dbName;Uid=user; Pwd=pWord" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I try to access the database from the website I get an error:

> Configuration Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>   Parser Error Message: The connection name 'LocalSqlServer' was not found in the applications configuration or the connection string is empty.
>
> Source Error:

I am running this site on IIS via Visual Studio 10. Any ideas what steps I'm missing?

Comment: Looks to me like you are looking for a connection string named `'LocalSqlServer' ` but there isn't one in the .config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBName;Uid=user;Pwd=pWord" provider="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Something like above should work.

Comment: it should be **providerName="System.Data.SqlClient** but this worked!

Comment: Oops typo...yeah it should be providerName

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for a connection string named "LocalSqlServer", yet you are adding a connection string named "SQLConnectionString".

Change this to:

`<add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Provider=ProvName;Server=Sname;Database=dbName;Uid=user; Pwd=pWord" />`

Comment: This may have worked too but it's working now and I don't want to touch it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Do a search for the phrase "LocalSqlServer" in all your config and code (.cs?) files.  It is being references somewhere else...not just the connection-strings config area.

The "name" attribute is used in other places in the code to look up the actual connection string.

I like Agent Ransack for looking in files for a specific string.

When you find the other reference, you can replace it with "MySuperSpecialConnectionStringName" (as seen below, an alteration of your original code).